# Why android source file is all red in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I made a basic application in Android Studio from guide
It works fine in emulator
But when I try to go to some sources, android.content.Context in particular it looks all red - half of imports are red 'Cannot find declaration to go' [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5VMp.png)
Why is it so and how can I fix it making it black and look into android.annotation.AttrRes for example?

Comment: you're inside a class you have no control over, what does it matter how it looks ?

Answer (score -1):

your Mapper 4.x is not supported in android studio that's y the modules are unable to import, I believe there is a setup problem, you should follow the steps from the below link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/setup

once done with setup make sure you are using the latest dependency of google maps

"compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'"